# Is it possible to have an abstract model inside another abstract model in Django/Djongo?

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I'm trying to add a model class with abstract=True in meta to another abstract class.For example,

```
class MainRecord(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    X_data  = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=X,
        model_form_class= X_Form,
    )

class X(models.Model):
    HRCT = models.BooleanField()
    Y = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Y,
        model_form_class=Y_Form,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Y(models.Model):
    Y_present = models.BooleanField()
    Location = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Location,
        model_form_class=Location_Form,

        )     
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

In Django admin, I'm able to see the embedded fields and it's corresponding checkboxes. I'm able to add/update values for the boolean field HRCT (Embedded from class X) but I'm not able to save the values/updates in the fields embedded from class Y to class X.

Comment: The idea of an abstract model is exactly that: that it is not a model stored in the database, but used to subclass and thus meak concrete models with the fields defined in the abstract one. But perhaps I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it makes more sense now.